# jQuery and css()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a piece of code from FancyBox ...

**JQUERY**

```
// Set custom style, close if clicked, change title type and overlay color

$(".mainmenu").fancybox({
    wrapCSS: 'fancybox-custom',
    closeClick: false,
    topRatio: 0,
    scrolling: 'no',
    fitToView: 'false',
    helpers: {
        title: {
            type: 'inside'
        },
        overlay: {
            css: {
                'background': 'url(img/misc/fancybox_overlay.png)'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

and additionally, I would like to add the following line to it, but somwhow it doesn't seem to work - getting tons of syntax errors here.

**JQUERY**

```
$(".blabla").css({"background-color":"yellow"});
```

Would be great if anyone could help.

Comment: Where are you adding it ?  What are the errors ? Please do not let us guess. `$(".blabla").css({"background-color":"yellow"}); ` is syntactically correct.

Comment: second line, under `$(".mainmenu").fancybox({`

Comment: Well, that's wrong. You cannot put an arbitrary  statement inside an object literal. Put it after or before the `fancybox` call. If that doesn't work like you want it to, you should explain *exactly* what you are trying to do, what the setup is, etc. Otherwise helping you is going to be difficult.

Comment: But then it will be added to the CSS by default (when the site is loaded). I only want it to be added when a certain link `.maincontent` is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Add your css here:

```
css : {
    'background' : 'url(img/misc/fancybox_overlay.png)',
    'background-color': 'yellow',

}
```

**EDITED:**

After seen the above discussion on the basis of the answer will be:

```
$(".maincontent").click(function(){
   $(this).css('background-color','yellow');
});
```

Answer (score -2):

I reckon that should be:

`$(".blabla").css("background-color", "yellow");`

Comment: `.css` accepts an object. And even if it didn't, you would get a runtime error, not a syntax error.